# Downgrade OpenSSL for Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, openssl

I am trying to connect to a broken server using Python that only works with OpenSSL 1.0.1. If I connect using OpenSSL 1.0.2 it fails with an EOF error. There's no way around it, trust me.

The latest Python 2.7 (also a requirement) install for Windows - 2.7.11 - ships with OpenSSL 1.0.2:

```
>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015'
```

Ideally I'd like to just switch out the DLLs, but I can't find any OpenSSL DLLs in the Python directory. Is Python statically linked to OpenSSL? Is there any *simple* way I can downgrade it, other than just using an older version of Python? If not, how do I know which version of Python switched to 1.0.2?

(Please no comments about how this is bad security, or how the server should be fixed, etc.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: How is this not about programming and development?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Python changelog](https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/tip/Misc/NEWS) it looks like Python 2.7.9 uses OpenSSL 1.0.1j and 2.7.10 uses 1.0.2a, so that is an option. Still it would be better if I could use the latest OpenSSL 1.0.1 with the latest Python 2.7 so any other answers are still appreciated!

Comment: It indeed seems that each version of Python is linked to a specific version of OpenSSL. So your only option is to downgrade. If you are really desperate, you could install the old OpenSSL library and use `ctypes` to write your own Python implementation of OpenSSL. See http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Determining-version-of-OpenSSL-linked-against-python-td4333385.html. But that would be a major undertaking.